# Best way to index a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

Is it a  good practice to have multiple index for same column in a table?

Eg. There is table A with column  `col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6`

Indexes

1. `Index1` on (col1,col2,col3)
2. `Index2` on (col4,col2,col6)
3. `Index3` on (col2,col1,col3,col4,col5)

In this case `col1,col2,col3` are part of more than one index for the table A. Is it not enough to have each column part of `single index`?

What is the use of having `same column` in `multiple index`. please clarify.

Comment: The order of the columns inside the index matters. Different queries will be able to use these indexes.

Comment: you should create indexes based on your needs. about indexes with multiple columns - rule of thumb says that the sub trees should be a small as possible (meaning the column with the greatest cardinality should be the prefix).

Answer (score 0):

It depends;)

In a lot of cases it's very usefull to have several indexes containing the same column.

See also this article at Ask Tom:
[Column order in Index](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5671539468597)

Whether an index helps depends a lot on your data and your query. Especially percentage of records, your query returns, is important.

The following sample is a little bit simplified, but in general it's how the system works:

Imagine, your database stores 10 records on each database block and your query has to return 10% of all records. In this case every 10th record has to be returned. In the worst case, you have to read every database block (full table scan). In this case an Index will slow down the query because you have to read the index additionally.

There are different opinions when to use an Index. My rule of thumb is this:

If 1% or less is selected, then an Index is good

If 10% or more is selected, then a full table scan is good

else (1%-9%) a more detailed analysis is required